# C# loop statements, help needed for a newbie

Tags: c#

I’m quite a newbie at c# and need some help with some loop statements.

I’m practising by designing a program that calculates cost per mile (which is 50p) and adds £30.00 every 1000 as a wear $ tear charge.

I’m having problems getting my head around the logic, if anyone could give me a few tips that would be great.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input start milleage:");
            decimal StartMile = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Input Finish milleage:");
            decimal FinishMile = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            decimal TotalMilleage = FinishMile - StartMile;

            if (TotalMilleage < 1000)

                TotalMilleage = TotalMilleage / 2;

                Console.WriteLine("Total charge for hire:{0:C}", TotalMilleage);


            Theres the code Ive done so far :S
```

Comment: Can we see the code you have tried?

Comment: Post the code you have so far so we can see what you've done.  As a hint, you shouldn't need to use a loop to solve this - you can do it with simple arithmetic.

Comment: @Shaddai Hurry up before you get tons of -1. Usually you may show what have you tried in the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need loop just make expression like this, Assuming £30 only charged after 1000 miles.

```
double price = 0.5 * DistanceInMile + ((int)(DistanceInMile /1000)) *30;
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` rounds up if the fractional part is `>= 0.5`

Comment: You are right @Rawling, corrected

Answer (score 2):

**Asuming miles is an `int`**

Not sure I get the question but:

```
double price = 0.5 * miles + 30 * (miles / 1000);
```

That way with 1200 miles you will add just once the £30.00. If you want to add it twice:

```
int times = miles / 1000;
if (miles % 1000 != 0)
    times++;
double price = 0.5 * miles + 30 * times;
```

Comment: Assuming miles is an `int`; if it's a floating type, you'll end up with partial £30s. (Your second block works around this.)

Comment: Yes, I assumed it without even thinking..

Answer (score 0):

```
route.Cost = 0.5 * route.Length + (Math.Floor(route.Length / 1000)) * 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out arithmetic is better for this, however as this is as a programming exercise, there are many ways you can do this.

Firstly, asuming you are using a whole number of miles

```
int miles=4555; // example mile count;
decimal cost=0; // starting cost;
int mileCounter=0;

for (int i=1; i<=miles;i++) {
  cost += 0.5m;
  mileCounter++;
  if ( mileCounter == 1000) {
    mileCounter = 0;
    cost += 30;
  }
}
```

alternatively you can not use mile counter and use maths to calculate

```
for (int i=1; i<=miles;i++) {
  cost += 0.5m;
  if ((i % 1000) == 0) {
    cost += 30;
  }
}
```

You could forgo the invidiual mile loop

```
decimal cost = 0.5m * miles;
for (int i=1000; i<= miles; i+=1000) {
  cost += 30;
}
```

And finally the straight arithmetic approach

```
decimal cost = 0.5m * miles + (30 * Math.Truncate(miles/1000m));
```